# Working out the value of $x$ on two triangle with the same area in the form $a+\sqrt b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Here are two triangles T1 and T2.

The lengths of the sides are in centimeters.

The area of triangle T1 is equal to the area of triangle T2.

Work out the value of x, giving your answer in the form $a+ \sqrt b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

**I'm in maths set 5 and this is the final question so i have no idea how to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

[image: Two triangles]

Answer (score 2):

My monitor is fuzzy, and I cannot read upside down. So I will assume that the legs of the right triangle are $1+x$ and $x-2$. You can use the same strategy if the expressions are different.

The right triangle has area $\frac{1}{2}(1+x)(x-2)$.

As to the isosceles triangle, it has area $\frac{1}{2}x^2\sin(30^\circ)$.

Set these areas equal to each other. We get
$$\frac{(1+x)(x-2)}{2}=\frac{x^2}{4}.$$
Multiply through by $4$. We get $2x^2-2x-4=x^2$, that is, $x^2-2x-4=0$. Solve, using the Quadratic Formula, and discarding the negative root. We get
$x=\frac{2+\sqrt{20}}{2}$, which can be simplified to the desired form.